# Fragment remove and commit on onPause() throws exception

Tags: android

In my application there is a fragment activity containing three tabs(map,list,settings). I have put remove and commit at onPause() method of map tab(extends fragment). When i toggle between tabs, it is working fine but when I move to next page(next activity) and come back, it throws nullpointer exception.

Because when I switch to next activity, onPause() map fragment has been removed and committed and when comes back it found it null and throws exception. I am unable to figure out, where to place my onPause() method code or how to init fragment again on restart or resume.

public class LocatorMainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

```
public class MapSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    GoogleMap map;

    public MapSectionFragment() {

    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onDestroyView()
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();

        Log.e("", "onDestroyView");

        /*try{

            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));

            ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();


            //ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
            //getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            //ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("", "Exception::" + e.toString());
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
        Log.e("", "onPause"); 

        try{

            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));

            ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            //if(ft.isAddToBackStackAllowed()){
                //ft.hide(fragment);
            if(ft.isAddToBackStackAllowed()){

                Log.e("", "back stack allowed"); 
                ft.remove(fragment);
                //ft.addToBackStack(getTag());
                //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

            //}

            //getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            //ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("", "Exception::" + e.toString());
        }
    }


/*  
    @Override
    public void onResume(){

        super.onResume();
        Log.e("inner", "onResume"); 

    }*/


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("inner", "onStop"); 

        //mReturningWithResult = false;

    }

    View rootView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //code
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Please suggest me where I am wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: why u want to remove the fragment every time when u are switching activity

Comment: Because I am using SupportMapFragment to display map and if I will not remove it again n again, it gives Inflate exception.

Answer (score 2):

In my working map fragment code, I've got the remove/commit of the map fragment (I'm using SupportMapFragment) within the onDestroyView() method, and I've got the initialization of the map within the onActivityCreated() method, as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    myMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.id_for_your_map_fragment);
    if (myMapFragment == null) {
        myMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        /* Code omitted here... all you have to do here is get your
         * fragment manager and run a replace() operation to swap the new fragment in
         */
    }
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView () {
    super.onDestroyView();

    try {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(myMapFragment).commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally, within onResume(), I run this check to make sure that the map is not null; if it is, I run the getMap() method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (myMap == null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        myMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.id_for_your_map_fragment);
        myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
    }
}
```

Having these snippets arranged in the places specified above has worked for me so far. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hougsworth but the case is that when i will commit at onDestroyView(), it always throws below exception:                  11-11 07:57:20.870: E/inner(3466): onStop
11-11 07:57:20.870: E/(3466): @onStop()
11-11 07:57:20.900: E/(3466): onDestroyView
11-11 07:57:20.900: E/(3466): Exception::java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState                                                                                                                     Thats why I kept commit in onPause(), that will be called before onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: I tried keeping onDestroy code inside onPause. but when returns from next activity to map activity, myMapFragment  is always null. Please suggest.

Comment: you should call super.onDestroyView(); after removing the myMapFragment.

Answer (score 2):

my issue resolved by putting these code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        super.onStart();

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onDestroyView()
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if (fragment.isResumed()) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Comment: Ah, sorry for the slow reply! Good to see that you've resolved the problem, though.